# HTTP2: How to indicate support for it? Is there a "Alternate-Protocol" for HTTP2?

Tags: http2

So I just upgraded to nginx 1.9.5 which supports HTTP2.

I replaced all `listen spdy` by `listen http2`, removed `spdy_headers_comp` directive and also removed `add_header Alternate-Protocol 443:npn-spdy/3;`

Then I opened my site in Firefox, opened network monitor, and voila: `Version: HTTP/2.0`

But how does Firefox know my site supports HTTP2? Does it always first try to connect via HTTP2 before trying HTTP1.1?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[HTTP/2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7540) sites are deployed over [TLS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security).

Browsers use a TLS extension called [ALPN](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7301) to tell the server what protocols they can speak.
Browsers always send this TLS extension, and always include both HTTP/2 and HTTP/1.1 (and may also include the old SPDY protocol).

The server receives the list of protocols that browsers can speak, and if the server supports HTTP/2 (and if a number of other conditions are met - in particular regarding the TLS protocol version and the cipher suite), the server decides to speak HTTP/2 with the browser, and sends the chosen protocol back to the browser, again using the ALPN extension.

If the server does not support HTTP/2 then it will send to the browser that it can only speak HTTP/1.1 via the ALPN extension.

If the server does not support the ALPN extension, then it will not send it to the browser, and the browser will default to speak HTTP/1.1 to that server.

Comment: OK, but why did Google recommend to add a `Alternate-Protocol: 443:npn-spdy/3` header when using SPDY? Why not do it the same way as HTTP2 does it (ALPN)?

Comment: `Alternate-Protocol` is used by servers to tell clients where they can connect _directly_ with the given protocol. Your example just says that Google servers support SPDY/3 (the predecessor of HTTP/2) via NPN (the predecessor of ALPN). For example an HTTP/1.1 server could reply with `Alternate-Protocol: 8443:h2` to tell the client to connect to a _different_ port (8443) without using ALPN, knowing that behind that port there is a HTTP/2 server. Without this header, a client would not know what protocol to speak on port 8443. For an ALPN capable server, `Alternate-Protocol` is just informative.